# Hibernate cannot alter tables during deploy to Heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku

I am trying to deploy my web app to Heroku. I have configured Hibernates (as the persistence provider) to do the following:

- create schema based on entities;
- fill data from sql script;

Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("model");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    String dbUrl = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
    String username = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME");
    String password = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD");

    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
    basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(password);
    return basicDataSource;
}


private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "test_data.sql");
    return properties;
}
```

However, it seems that Hibernate cannot alter existing Heroku schema:

```
2016-07-16T15:04:20.978399+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-16 15:04:20 ERROR SchemaExport:483 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table fueling drop constraint fuel_type
2016-07-16T15:04:20.975268+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-16 15:04:20 ERROR SchemaExport:484 - ERROR: relation "customer" does not exist
2016-07-16T15:04:20.985169+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-07-16 15:04:20 ERROR SchemaExport:484 - ERROR: relation "fueling" does not exist
```

Could you please advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did those relations really exist in the database prior to the deployment? What you are seing is the standard behaviour, it doesn't really need to be an error.

Comment: The issue is that I want hibernate to create these tables. I am using this property `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop"` and it doesn't force Hibernate to create tables.